# xacro prase the value from YAML by giving variable

Tags: yaml, ros, gazebo-simu

Environment: ROS Noetic, Gazebo11

I try to use xacro with YAML, but there is a problem about argument of variable:

My yaml:

```xml
---
  color_0: "1 1 1 1.0"
  color_1: "0 0 0 1.0"
  color_2: "0.84 0 0 1.0"
  color_3: "0.55 0.24 1 1.0"
  color_4: "0.01 0.53 0 1.0"
```

Because I want to use different value at different time.

So I tried to load the value as below:

```xml
<xacro:property name="YAML_FILE" value="$(find gazebo_ros_model_color)/configs/colors.yaml" />
<xacro:property name="COLORS" value="${load_yaml(YAML_FILE)}"/>
    
<xacro:arg name="color" default="color_0" />
<color>${COLORS[${color}]}</color>
```

But it cause the ERROR :((

```sh
...
invalid expression: ${color 
when evaluating expression 'COLORS['${color'
    ...
```

Is it possible to get the value from YAML by key variable given?
Or other solving method?

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The different use of `xacro:property`, `xacro:arg`, and `xacro:params` is:

`xacro:arg` is use `$(arg VAR)`
`xacro:property` and `xacro:params` are use `${VAR}`

So, I solve my problem as below:

```
<xacro:arg name="color" default="color_${id_num}" />
<color>${COLORS['$(arg color)']}</color>
```

And I also tried to use xacro:property, but CAN NOT use it like:

```
<xacro:property name="color" value="color_0" />
<color>${COLORS['${color}']}</color>
```